# How to pause for loop until script in separate tab has finished executing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that take c.30 URLs from a page and opens each of them in a new tab.

```
let allItems = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++ ) {  
  let currentUrl = allItems[i].href;
  window.open(currentUrl, '_blank')
}
```

Once the new tab is open, I inject a new script (foreground script) into that new tab. This injection is triggered by this code in the background.js file

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    current_active_tabId = tabId;

    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.includes('https://www.website.com')) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(current_active_tabId, {file: 'foreground.js'}, function() {
            console.log('injected and executed');
        })
    }
});
```

My problem is that the foreground script takes c.10 seconds to execute. Therefore I don't want to loop through the next URL until the foreground script has finished executing. I don't want to use a timeout function (sometimes it takes more or less than 10 seconds).

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You could [communicate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) with your foreground script and check for the status

Comment: Thanks @NullDev. I have thought about sending a message from the foreground script to the content script when the foreground script has finished executing each time... but I'm not sure how to "pause" the content script in the first place?

Comment: You can either use [promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) or [generators](https://javascript.info/generators) for that.

Comment: Don't use `window.open` - switch to chrome.tabs.create() or update() in the background script, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346193).